# Angular2 app.module.ts error

Tags: angular, typescript

Me and some friends are doing a major school project a nice web app and hum I have some errors in my app.module.ts that just popped up which is weird because I do have them and they don't!

The error :

```
Error:(32, 11) TS2345:Argument of type '{ imports:typeof BrowserModule[]; exports: typeof SignupFormComponent[];    declarations: (typeof S...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'.Types of property 'declarations' are incompatible.Type '(typeof SignupFormComponent | typeof AppComponent | typeof LoaderComponent | typeof MenuComponent...' is not assignable to type '(any[] | Type<any>)[]'.Type 'typeof SignupFormComponent | typeof AppComponent | typeof LoaderComponent | typeof MenuComponent ...' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'.Type 'typeof ViewRecipeModalComponent' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any>'.Type 'typeof ViewRecipeModalComponent' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'.Cannot assign a 'private' constructor type to a 'public'     constructor type.
```

this is the app.module.ts

```
    import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
    import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
    import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

    import './rxjs-extensions';
    import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
    import {AppRoutingModule, routedComponents} from './app-routing.module';
    import {Backend} from './shared/services/backend';
    import {MenuComponent} from './menu/menu.component';
    import {PlannerComponent} from './planner/planner.component';
    import {PlannerMenuComponent} from './planner/planner-menu/planner-menu.component';
    import {LoginComponent} from './forms/login/login.component';
    import {SignupFormComponent} from './forms/signup/signup-form.component';
    import {ListsComponent} from './lists/lists.component';
    import {ListEntryControlsComponent} from "./lists/list-entry-controls/list-entry-controls.component";
    import {ListEntryFoodComponent} from './lists/list-entry-food/list-entry-food.component';
    import {ListEntryRecipeComponent} from './lists/list-entry-recipe/list-entry-recipe.component';
    import {ListTopBarComponent} from './lists/list-top-bar/list-top-bar.component';
    import {LoaderComponent} from "./loader/loader.component";
    import {ListErrorComponent} from "./lists/list-error/list-error.component";
    import {RecipeModalComponent} from "./forms/modals/recipe/recipe-modal.component";
    import {CreateFoodModalComponent} from "./forms/modals/create-food/create-food-modal.component";
    import {ViewRecipeModalComponent} from "./forms/modals/view-recipe/view-recipe-modal.component";
    import {Typeahead} from "./forms/typehead/typehead.component";
    import {PlannerWeekGridComponent} from "./planner/planner-week-grid/planner-week-grid.component";
    import {PlannerWeekCellComponent} from "./planner/planner-week-cell/planner-week-cell.component";
    import {DynamicUnitComponent} from "./forms/dynamic-unit/dynamic-unit.component";
    import {TagsEditorComponent} from "./forms/tags-editor/tags-editor.component";
    import {PromoBooksComponent} from "./books/promo-books/promo-books.component";

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpModule
      ],
      exports: [
    SignupFormComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoaderComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    PlannerMenuComponent,
    PlannerWeekCellComponent,
    PlannerWeekGridComponent,
    PlannerComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignupFormComponent,
    ListsComponent,
    ListErrorComponent,
    ListEntryControlsComponent,
    ListEntryFoodComponent,
    ListEntryRecipeComponent,
    ListTopBarComponent,
    ViewRecipeModalComponent,
    RecipeModalComponent,
    CreateFoodModalComponent,
    TagsEditorComponent,
    Typeahead,
    DynamicUnitComponent,
    routedComponents,
    PromoBooksComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    Backend
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

I just re-cloned the whole project and the issue persist. I'm using webstorm latest release. By the way, I'm able to npm start the app and run it I just can't figure out this error in webstorm. The error starts at the first bracket of ng module.

Comment: If the code works then this is likely just to be a problem with your webstorm. Have you got all the necessary plugins required for typescript? Have a look here http://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/typescript-support.html

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a private constructor.